# blanks lines in between data rows show up when using SPOOL in SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to spool a large query in sqlplus but for some reason, I see 2 blank lines every 558 rows to be exact.

I spool as such:

```
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET LINES 1000
SET FEEDBACK off
SET HEADING OFF
SET ARRAYSIZE 10000
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
Spool D:\IPORT15.csv
select query
Spool OFF;
EXIT
```

I thought SET NEWPAGE was supposed to take care of that??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by setting: "SET PAGES 0"